# Sum statement counts everything, or northing

Tags: sql, sum, conditional-statements, where-clause

I am almost finished with my project, but i still have one issue left. 
I need to create a summary with an sql code. The code is like this:

"SELECT SUM(prices of a column), select others FROM blablabla WHERE condintion 1 is true OR condition 2 is true OR condition 3 is true GROUP BY blablabla;"

The problem is, is that i can't use the above because of the OR. Whenever i use OR, it see's that condintion 1 for example is true, so he will ignore the rest of the conditions, but i need them to to see if they are true. The problem with using a "AND" instead of an "OR" causes to set the result to nothing because all three can't always be true.

So the bottomline is, My query needs to count some fields in a column where a field meets a condition. I use multiple conditions because there are diffrent kinds of products, but i somehow can't use the conditions al togheter because the statement counts everything whever one condition is met, or counts nothing because they can't always be true all three of them.

how do i fix this?

thanks

Comment: Try `SELECT SUM(CASE prices_of_a_column WHEN NULL THEN 0 ELSE prices_of_a_column END), ...`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I have completely understand the question, I think this is what you are looking for

```
SELECT SUM(prices of a column) 
FROM blablabla 
WHERE 
(condintion 1 is true OR condition 2 is true)
AND 
(condintion 1 is true OR condition 3 is true) 
AND 
(condintion 2 is true OR condition 3 is true) 
GROUP BY blablabla;
```

OR may be

```
SELECT SUM(prices of a column) 
FROM blablabla 
WHERE 
(condintion 1 is true AND condition 2 is true)
OR 
(condintion 1 is true AND condition 3 is true) 
OR 
(condintion 2 is true AND condition 3 is true) 
GROUP BY blablabla;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(prices column) as Total
FROM yourTable
WHERE condition1 is true
GROUP BY columnBLabla

UNION ALL

SELECT SUM(prices column)
FROM yourTable
WHERE condition2 is true
GROUP BY columnBLabla

UNION ALL

SELECT SUM(prices column)
FROM yourTable
WHERE condition3 is true
GROUP BY columnBLabla
```

Result

**`Total`**

```
100 -- total price when condition 1 is true
230 -- total price when condition2 is true
900 -- total price when condition 3 is true
```

Comment: I dont think i can use that because i select multiple columns besides the sum

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding but, could you use a case statement? You could put each of the conditions in its own "When X is true A" statement. Then by varying/or not varying the A you could make category to summarize on.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN condition1 THEN prices_of_a_column ELSE 0 END) AS prices1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN condition2 THEN prices_of_a_column ELSE 0 END) AS prices2,
  SUM(CASE WHEN condition3 THEN prices_of_a_column ELSE 0 END) AS prices3
FROM blabla
GROUP BY blabla
```